# jquery custom filter does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

The filter itself is pretty easy:

```
$.expr[':'].valid = function(a) {
    var phone = a.value.replace(/\D/g,''),
        phonesub = phone.substr(0, 2);
    return (phonesub == '79' || phonesub == '89') && phone.length == 11 
}
```

I just want to check if `phone` length us 11 and it starts with `79` or `89`. However:

```
$(":valid")
[<input type=​"text" id=​"phone1" name=​"phone1" value>​]
```

it's clear that value is "".

Why my filter doesn't work?

BTW, at the same time, there is another input on the DOM:

```
<input type="text" id="phone2" name="phone2" value="" disabled="">
```

and it's not getting matched by the filter. Is it affected by `disabled`?

Let's change it's value:

```
$("#phone2")
[<input type=​"text" id=​"phone2" name=​"phone2" value disabled>​]
$("#phone2").val("79111111111")
[<input type=​"text" id=​"phone2" name=​"phone2" value disabled>​]
$("#phone2").val()
"79111111111"
$(":valid")
[<input type=​"text" id=​"phone1" name=​"phone1" value>​]
```

I'm desperate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because "valid" its reserved filter name in jQuery. Use "validPhone" or other name instead of "valid".

Comment: Muchos gracies, Arturka :) This is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since `a` is a dom element you should write

```
a.value.replace(/\D/g,''),
```

or

```
$(a).val().replace(/\D/g,''),
```

Comment: Yep, `value()` is a typo in my code (updated the question). Still, doesn't work properly.